# Using fix-boot but still stuck

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7

I have a laptop I used to use for college that was Ubuntu 10.4 /Vista / Win7.

I pulled it out and proceeded to install 12.04 advanced partitioning.

It was sda1 ubuntu / swap / vista / and sda5 win7. I deleted the ubuntu, swap and vista, leaving 7 alone.

I'm using it now but can't get to win7. I used fix-boot several times using variations on the advanced menus. So I finally purged grub and forced grup-pc in the advanced setting of fix-boot. Here is a link to the report;
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1225051/

I'm sure there is a way to edit the grub to get 7 to show as a boot choice and hope someone can point it out for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. When Win7 is installed after Vista, it pus some boot files in the Vista partition. When you deleted Vista, you removed also some Win7 boot files (eg BCD). That's why Win7 can't boot now.
2. Solution: fix the Windows boot via a Windows CD this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader
   Then use Boot-Repair `Recommended repair` to recover the GRUB menu.